# How do you define propertychain in owlready

Tags: owlready

Recently, I started to study owlready, and faced with much problem.
I defined a `PropertyChain` as follows.

```
class friend(Person >> Person, SymmetricProperty):
    pass

class potentialFriend(Person >> Person):
    # potentialFriend := friend o friend
    equivalent_to = PropertyChain([friend, friend])
```

I tried to get `person.potentialFriend.indirect()`, but failed. I read the source codes, since the doc on web is too simple, and found that `PropertyChain` works like a list, I thought it returned a `Property`. How do I compliment what I want?

How do you use PropertyChain? Is there some concrete examples.

PS: The source codes(.py files) indent with only two whitespaces, :o!

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"?

Comment: @StanislavKralin PropertyChain dose not return a property. How do I use it. If I call it as person.potentialFriend.indirect(), it reports error.

Comment: Well, documentation [says](http://owlready2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/properties.html#obtaining-indirect-relations-considering-subproperty-transitivity-etc) that `indirect()` takes into account subroperty, transitivity, reflexivity and symmetricity axioms (only). Probably property chains are supported only for serialization/saving, not for reasoning. In your case, another modelling approach is to make `potentialFriend` transitive superproperty of `friend`.

Comment: @StanislavKralin thank you very much. But I just want to define a property T that is the chain of properties R and S, ie T = R o S. How do I  define it?

Comment: [Example](https://bitbucket.org/jibalamy/owlready2/src/0a43f4ec0ca3ba7226892c23d8dce43609ff71a3/test/regtest.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#regtest.py-2980). You can also ask your questions here: http://owlready.8326.n8.nabble.com/

Comment: Asked and answered: http://owlready.8326.n8.nabble.com/How-do-you-define-a-chain-of-properties-td200.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
P.property_chain.append(PropertyChain([P1, P2]))
```

...where `P1` and `P2` are already created `ObjectProperties`. In your case, `P` is `potentialFriend`. `P1` and `P2` are both `friend`.

Answer (score 0):

For the reasoner to infer the property chain, don't forget to set its parameter  `infer_property_values` to `True` :

```
  sync_reasoner(infer_property_values = True)
```

After that, the reasoner manages to infer the property and you can get it with `person.potentialFriend.indirect()`.